# drush make and drupalcode patches

Tags: version-control, drush

I would like to download the stable version of a project and apply a [patch](http://drupalcode.org/project/flot.git/commitdiff/0b9d38d28e9f66cee239e7f92ccd2a368ce377c7). This patch was not submitted but applied directly to the project. I have the following drush make file (just a test snippet)

```
; Drush make script for the level platform install profile and features
core = 6.20
api = 2
projects[drupal][type] = core

projects[flot][dir] = "contrib"
projects[flot][version] = "1.2"
projects[flot][patch][] = "http://drupalcode.org/project/flot.git/patch/0b9d38d28e9f66cee239e7f92ccd2a368ce377c7"
```

This tells me that the patch has failed. If I download the file and use patch -p0 it will patch correctly.

Anyone have an idea why this is not working, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a git based patch, I believe that you with drush need to use generic patched, which with git can be created like this:

```
git diff --no-prefix > file.patch
```

Comment: Thanks, that has identified the cause. Still trying to think of a neat way to reference these patches in drush make via drupalcode.

Comment: Have a look at http://drupal.org/node/745224